# Where will the object inside a function go when i call it?

Tags: python

1 - Where will the object inside a function go when i call it ?

2 - Will the object go the the print statement to print or when i call the function will directly go to the terminal to be shown on the screen ?

```
def myname():
    return 'hello world'
print(myname())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function does not print anything on its own. It is called, and after its execution it outputs a `'hello world'` to whatever called it. This value is then passed as an input to `print`, which causes it to show up on stdout

Answer (score 1):

`myname()` is an expression that evaluates to a `str` object, just like the string literal `'hello world'` itself. `print` receives a `str` object; it has no idea whether it came from a literal or a more complex expression, but it does the same thing with it regardless of its source: it writes it to standard output.

Comment: wait a second..... do you mean myname() is the 'hello world' it is the object itself ???????

Comment: the object inside a function go when i call it ? --> there is no object inside your function, there is a returned string though

Comment: so the print statement doesn't care about myname() it cares only about what it returns ?? once the print stetemnt gets what myname() got myname() will disappear right ?????

Comment: Yes, `print` knows nothing about the *code* used to generate its argument, only the result of that code.

Comment: what about the function being an object itself but : 'function' object has no attribute '__mro__'

Comment: @pippo1980 What about it? (Are you sure you are commenting on the right question/answer?)

Comment: A `str` value *is* an object; *all* values in Python are objects of some class or another.

Comment: @chepner the OP was talking about : the object inside a function go when i call it  , so I figured out that fiunction itself could be an object but cant get its base class as obj

Comment: The function *is* an object, but you are confusing the function (which does not have an `__mro__` attribute) with the type of the function (`from types import FunctionType; FunctionType.__mro__` provides `(<class 'function'>, <class 'object'>)`.

Answer (score 0):

input as main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3



def myname():
    return 'Hello World'

print(myname())

a = myname()

print(a)

myname()


try: 
    print( myname.__mro__ )
    
except Exception as Expt:
    
    print(Expt)
```

output :

```
Hello World
Hello World
'function' object has no attribute '__mro__'
```